# error - installation of spicetify on Mac

Tags: mac, spotify

I am getting the following error in terminal when I try to install spicetify (Mac OS - Ventura 13.0, Chip M2):

```
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: ./spicetify
```

Comment: Even though there’s a great deal of missing info, that error alone should get you down the right path:  you’re using the wrong architecture to compile/execute the code. Either you have  x86/64 libraries on an ARM (Apple Silicon) CPU or  vice versa.